# Como puedo ingresar datos de una tabla hija a una padre desde un formulario

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo dos tablas: `persona` y `usuario`.

Desde un formulario quiero insertar datos en `persona` y `usuario`.

El `usuario` tiene que tener el **id** de la `persona`.

¿Cómo puedo realizarlo con php?

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SO en español!  Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para entender cómo funciona este sitio y como elaborar correctamente las preguntas.  En este caso [no has hecho nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/263200), y poco podremos ayudarte. No hacemos el código de los demas, sin embargo arreglamos código que os dé problemas o esteis encallados.  Si te lees bien los enlaces que te acabo de pasar lo entenderás y modificarás tu pregunta para que sea bien recibida por la comunidad y alguien quiera ayudarte.

Comment: Amigo tu pregunta no es suficiente para darte una respuesta, muestra lo que intentas, y con gusto te podremos ayudar. A simple vista solo debes hacer 2 consultas diferentes una que apunte a cada tabla, y para que el usuario tenga el id Persona usas una llave foranea.(Aqui ayudamos a solucionar problemas de codigo bro)

Comment: saludos, te sugiero agregar parte de tu código que ya tienes avanzado para poder darte una mejor respuesta.